# How to detect DOM modification event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I have been trying to get listen to DOM change event for a several hours, however still cannot get it working.

I need to detect events that are showed in `Chrome Debug Tools` as changes displayed as pink color.

Here is what I've tried

```
  function listenForDomModified(node, listener) {
            node.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", listener, false);
            var iframes = node.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
            for (var i = 0, len = iframes.length, doc; i < len; ++i) {
                // Catch and ignore errors caused by iframes from other domains
                try {
                    doc = iframes[i].contentDocument || iframes[i].contentWindow.document;
                    doc.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", listener, false);
                } catch (ex) {}
            }
        }
        var findElements = function () {
            elements.iframeBlock = $(SELECTOR.IFRAME_BLOCK);
        };
        var onIframeChange = function (e) {

            console.log("CHANGE !!!");
            alert("DOM CHANGES");
        };
        var setListeners = function () {
            listenForDomModified(elements.iframeBlock[0],onIframeChange);
            elements.iframeBlock.bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
                  if (e.target.innerHTML.length > 0) {
                    alert("ON CHANGE");
                  }
                  alert("ON CHANGE");
            });
            //elements.iframeBlock.change(onIframeChange);
        };
```

Please note, I tried these methods separately.

But still cannot get my function called. However `Chrome` displays these changes.

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$(document).on('change', function () { /*code*/ });
```

Comment: Yes, as you can see from my question, it is just commented out

Comment: You have not any documents' change listener in your code. The commented row at the bottom of your function does not do what mine do. Note also that you dont even call the function setListeners(), you just define it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery approach:

```
$("iframe").contents().find('body').on("change", function() {
   alert("DOM CHANGES");
});
```

*not tested...*